# How to implement interface that uses templates?

Tags: java, linked-list, immutability

I'm expected to implement immutable list interface that looks like this:

```
public interface InterfList<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public InterfList<T> append(T t);
    //More abstract methods follow
}
```

When I've let netbeans implement the interface for me, this appeared:

```
public class MyList implements InterfList  {
  private Object value;
  @Override
  public InterfList append(Object t) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }
}
```

However, I want to keep the template so that only the proper type of object is accepted. Eg.:

```
public class MyList<T> implements InterfList  {
  private T value;
  @Override
  public InterfList<T> append(T t) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }
}
```

The first approach would allow any kinds objects to be stored in list making it quite a mess.

The first approach, however, is marked as error in netbeans:

> `MyList` is not abstract and does not implement method `append(object)` in `InterfList`

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: I added the error which I've forgotten to add when posting the question. According to the fact that an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24099290/607407) has been posted in the meantime, I believe my problem wasn't *that obscure*.

Comment: Well I just took a guess with that answer, I want to make sure... I'll and an explanation of why it solved the error.

Comment: Thanks you a lot. I originally didn't notice that the comment and the answer came from the same user - so I thought you're one of the guys who just randomly comment/downvote when they don't know the answer.

Comment: No, this is a good question. You just didn't add a small part. Not nearly worth a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
public class MyList<T> implements InterfList<T>  {

  private T value;

  @Override
  public InterfList<T> append(T t) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
  }
}
```

You want to implement `InterfList<T>`.

Since you were implementing `InterfList` without any type parameters, you're implementing `InterfList<Object>`, which causes an error with the `append` method, which takes `T` instead of an `Object`. You want to implement `InterfList<T>`.